# Is "listivew" a thing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

I was reviewing some suggested edits and though I usually skip wiki edits, one caught my eye: a proposed summary for the [listivew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listivew). Is [listivew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listivew) actually a thing or is it a misspelling of [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview)? I suspect the latter, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

As of right now, there are 32 questions with this tag.

Comment: I've looked into it a bit further. Even if [tag:listiview] is a thing, most or all of those 32 questions are clearly mis-tagged. I think I should re-tag all the questions with [tag:listview] and the [tag:listiview] tag will hopefully eventually disappear, right?

Comment: Looks like you're on with the re-tagging, so I won't interfere...

Comment: The errant tag was "listivew", but my brain read it as "listiview", which I thought was plausibly a thing. Once I realized it was a simple transposition error, I was confident to proceed with the re-tagging.

Comment: I just edited the last question, so the tag should be gone by tomorrow morning.

Comment: It is just an exmaple of a common porblem.  Otherwise an insight in how the human brain parses text, Google "Typoglycemia" and "If You Can Raed Tihs, You Msut Be Raelly Smrat" to learn more.

Comment: You do realise I'm going to call them Listiviews from now on? Damn you.

Comment: @TheBlueDog it is Listivew please pay attention.

Comment: @EricLevieil: Yeah, I got that, my response was a joke. Please pay attention ...

Comment: @TheBlueDog I think I will too. Reminds me of texty-text (from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBbmdlcRFXs)

Comment: I think Ive read this 10 times now and it still reads differently every time.